# unzip and process compressed data

Tags: bash, zip

I want to process zip files on the fly and I have an issue. When applying the following code.

```
for file in ./*.zip; do head -$(($(unzip -c $file | grep -n $channel_after | cut -f1,1 -d":"))) $file;done
```

The idea is to obtain all the lines up to $channel_after which is channel10. However I get the following output

PK;��L�
         ��p-  marks.txtUT    Q�K[Q�K[ux
                                           ��342�020��.(��QH��K�.J-�56���2�00��g(d$楧�X�[�q���fh`�+.�@��
                                         -��̭�sRR�J�*A,���vQn�3��������r ,54���\PK;��L�
                ��p-   ��marks.txtUTQ�K[ux

Whereas the original file looks like

```
12082008;pull done;ret=34;Y
08072008;push hanged;s=3;N
15082008;pull done;ret=34;Y
01062008;psuh done;ret=23;Y
18082007;old entry;old;N
08072008;push hanged;s=3;N
15082008;pull done;ret=34;Y
01062008;psuh done;ret=23;Y
18082007;old entry;old;N
08072008;push hanged;s=3;N
15082008;pull done;ret=34;Y
01062008;psuh done;ret=23;Y
18082007;old entry;old;N
08072008;push hanged;s=3;N
15082008;pull done;ret=34;Y
01062008;psuh done;ret=23;Y
18082007;old entry;old;N
Channel8
08072008;push hanged;s=3;N
15082008;pull done;ret=34;Y
01062008;psuh done;ret=23;Y
18082007;old entry;old;N
Channel9
08072008;push hanged;s=3;N
15082008;pull done;ret=34;Y
01062008;psuh done;ret=23;Y
18082007;old entry;old;N
Channel10
08072008;push hanged;s=3;N
15082008;pull done;ret=34;Y
01062008;psuh done;ret=23;Y
18082007;old entry;old;N
```

Why I am getting this error? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're applying `head` to the original zipfile without unzipping it: the first argument to `head` is the arithmetic expansion with command substitution, the second one is $file. `head` doesn't know how to read zip files.

I saved the sample data as `marks.txt` and zipped it with

```
zip 1.zip marks.txt
```

I was then able to run

```
channel_after=Channel8
for file in 1.zip ; do
    head -$(($(unzip -c $file | grep -n $channel_after | cut -f1,1 -d":"))) \
        <(unzip -c $file)
done
```

which printed all the lines up to `Channel8`.

Comment: could you please tell me exactly what to fix? thanks

Comment: As I don't posses the zip file, I don't know *exactly* what to fix. Maybe replace the second argument to `head` with something like `<(unzip -p $file)`. You might need to specify the name of the archived file, too.

Comment: I get this then : bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Comment: @JPV: See the detailed description in the updated answer. Next time, please provide more information so we don't have to guess.

Comment: @JPV: So, my answer was unaccepted in favour of the other one. Were you asking for explanation or code? I gave you both, BTW.

Comment: That was a mistake. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

Your version is:

```
for file in ./*.zip; do head -$(($(unzip -c $file | grep -n $channel_after | cut -f1,1 -d":"))) $file;done
```

What you should do is:

```
for file in ./*.zip; do head -$(($(unzip -c $file | grep -n $channel_after | cut -f1,1 -d":"))) <(unzip -c $file);done
```